# Android Transição entre Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment, actionbar

Tenho uma aplicação que contém 2 fragments.
Um fragment (A) é uma listagem de items e a toolbar tem um search, e o segundo (B) é o datalhe do item selecionado.
Consigo fazer a transição bem de A ->B e vice versa.
O meu problema está no search do framgent A (a pesquisa é sequencial, à medida que se vai escrevendo, a listagem é filtrada tendo em conta o campo da pesquisa).
Depois clico no item para ir para o delhalhe (e a toolbar fica sem o search, como pretendo), mas quando faço back queria manter o search aberta com o texto introduzido pelo utilizador.

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Kiotto, recomendo dar uma olhada no `OnBackStackChangedListener` que você pode adicionar ao `FragmentManager`. Com ele você consegue saber que o usuário voltou pro Fragment anterior e restaurar o `SearchView`.

Comment: Sem querer abusar muito, podias fazer um exemplo de código sff?

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, eu recomendaria a interface [`OnBackStackChangedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html), que registrada junto ao `FragmentManager` consegue tratar qualquer evento de transação de `Fragment's` **que gerem registros no `BackStack`**. Isso é, a cada transação, você precisa usar o [`FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)), o que você já deve estar fazendo.

O exemplo para o seu use case seria:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Seu codigo de inicializacao, caso haja
    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
    // Ou
    // getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    // Verifica se o Fragment inicial esta visivel
    // Caso afirmativo, atualizar o SearchView
}
```

Para recuperar o Fragment que está visível, você pode usar aquelas flags (isVisible, isHidden) ou até mesmo usar o `FragmentManager.findFragmentById` ou `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag` e verificar se voltou alguma instância.

---

Existe uma outra maneira, verificando o `BackStack`, mas não tenho certeza se é a melhor abordagem comparada com a anterior (chuto que não daria pra saber qual a última entrada que foi removida, e sim a última entrada que ainda está na pilha). Dessa maneira teria que recuperar o nome do `BackStackEntry` (lembrando de colocar o mesmo nome no `addToBackStack`) para verificar se o segundo `Fragment` foi removido.

Um exemplo seria:

```
Fragment fA = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FA");
Fragment fB = new Fragment();

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(R.id.container, fA).add(R.id.container, fB).addToBackStack("FA_FB").commit();
```

Depois no onBackStackChanged:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry entry = backfm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);

if(entry.getName().equals("FA_FB")) {
    // TODO Atualizar SearchView...
}
```

**Lembrando que o método acima eu não tenho certeza, preciso verificar em meu ambiente**